# How do I use multiple versions of Laravel on the same machine?

Tags: php, linux, laravel, composer-php

After that I had to contribute to one of Laravel 4 projects, I cloned it and just ran blindly `composer install`, to get the dependencies of 4...

However when I came back to projects of laravel 5, I had to re-run the command to continue working on them too..

So instead of re-running `composer` all the time, is there a neater alternative to have multiple versions of laravel on the same machine on the same user?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to have Laravel installed globally, and if this is the case, then you should install it locally instead (per project), so it won't conflict living in each project's `vendor/` folder.

Comment: I checked upon composer.json in the `~/.composer` and all it has is `require laravel/installer`, due to my old used command `composer global require laravel/installer`... so how do I require laravel locally as you described?

I understand it'll be like , create a project via composer, add the version of laravel you want , and then `composer install` per project, right?

Comment: Then I do not undestand how can you have shared laravel per two projects  otherway? If you got project A in folder A then it should have `A/vendor` and Laravel should be there too. Same for project B in separate directory  B. So how come you got it otherway?

Comment: Could it be symfony in the global vendor directory? because after I run `composer install` for each of them I see that it's what it is getting installed for each?

Comment: L uses Symphony components so that might be related. You can remove/hide whatever your global symphone and do `composer install` to check if it would install it locally.